# Purpose of simple wrapper function in C

Tags: c, wrapper

In [ex26](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex26.html) of 'Learn C the Hard Way' in the `db.c` file Zed defines two functions:

```
static FILE *DB_open(const char *path, const char *mode) {
return fopen(path, mode);
}
static void DB_close(FILE *db) {
fclose(db);
}
```

I have a hard time understanding the purpose/need for wrapping these very simple calls to `fopen` and `fclose`. What are, if any, the advantages of wrapping very simple functions, like the example given above?

Comment: By the library using the wrappers instead, a consumer of the library is free to change their implementation to something else without having to hack at the library code.

Comment: It's likely that you are somewhat confused by the fact that the code you've pasted in here isn't a very good wrapper - it exposes the exact parameters and types of the underlying implementation, meaning that if the implementation changes, the caller is likely to have to modified as well. A better wrapper would abstract out some of that so that it would be possible to change the implementation without causing the user of the code to change.

Comment: @MichaelKohne would it possible to abstract out in the given example, or is that more as general advice for when wrapping functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this particular case a wrapper is used to hide the detail that `DB_open`, `DB_read` or `DB_close` all map to file operations.

This approach implements an *abstraction layer* through which all database related functions are to be accessed. Also this provides *modularity*, which may later allow adding more methods to open/read/close databases.

As explained by Michael Kohne in the comments, this wrapper should be improved to totally hide e.g. the type of `FILE *db`, by substituting it with `struct DB_context *context;`.

Answer (score 1):

Wrappers, (or *stubs*), are often used to guard the other areas of your code from changes in the functions being wrapped.

It's also a useful way of interacting with dynamic libraries and shared objects.

Answer (score 0):

Basically a wrapper means , hiding all the related information of underlying routines by using our/a_developer's custom function.

You've mentioned that file name itself is db.c , so maybe the developer wants all the critical & important function which are used/declared must have starting of **DB_**